# Google Analytics GANTracker - How to use setCustomVariable in a IOS App?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-analytics, analytics

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {    

  [[GANTracker sharedTracker] startTrackerWithAccountID:kAnalyticsAccountId
                                           dispatchPeriod:kGANDispatchPeriodSec
                                                 delegate:nil];
    NSError *error;
    NSCalendar * calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents * components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit
                                                fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSString * stringTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d",components.hour, components.minute];

    if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] setCustomVariableAtIndex:1
                                                         name:@"TIME"
                                                        value:stringTime
                                                    withError:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"error in setCustomVariableAtIndex");
    }

  [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];  
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   return YES;

 }
```

Since the values are URL encoded, 16:30 becomes 16%3A30 in GA site. I want it to be displayed as it is.ie,16:30. How do I do this?
Also the custom variables i'm setting from other controllers are not getting updated.
For eg:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];

    NSError *errorMsg;

    if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] setCustomVariableAtIndex:2
                                                         name:@"DEVICE"
                                                        value:device.model
                                                    withError:&errorMsg]) {
        NSLog(@"error in setCustomVariableAtIndex2");
    }
}
```

This does not get updated. I am aware that it takes one day for the data to get reflected on the site. But only the custom variable(key 1) has data. Other keys shows "There is no data for this view" though i'm using index 2(refer above code).
Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

> Since the values are URL encoded, 16:30 becomes 16%3A30 in GA site. I want it to be displayed as it is.ie,16:30. How do I do this?

```
NSString *testme = @"16%3A30";
testme = [testme stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"testme = %@", testme); //16:30
```

Comment: Thanks David, but on my side I get the string as 16:30 only. Its when I pass it to google server using GANTracker 'setCustomVariableAtIndex' method, it gets updated on the site as 16%3A30.